WebView2 New Windows Request should open new Tab inside the Application instead
I am using WebView2 inside my WPF Project.
At the moment, the behaviour is - if a webpage tries to open a new Window, there is a WebView2 Window opening outside my application.
What I would like to achieve is, that I can add a TabItem and open the requested Window within this TabItem.
I've tried using the CoreWebView2 NewWindowsRequested Event, this is my code:
private async void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Cast sender to CoreWebView2
        CoreWebView2 coreWebView2Sender = (CoreWebView2)sender;

        // Create a new TabItem
        TabItem tab = new TabItem
        {
            Header = "Header"
        };

        // Add the new tab to the tabView
        tabView.Items.Add(tab);
        tabView.SelectedItem = tab;

        // Create a new WebView2 element
        WebView2 newWebView2 = new WebView2();

        // Set the new WebView2 element as content of the tab
        tab.Content = newWebView2;

        // Use the environment of the sending WebView2 element
        var environment = coreWebView2Sender.Environment;

        // Initialize the new WebView2 element
        await newWebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(environment);

        // Check if CoreWebView2 is initialized
        if (newWebView2.CoreWebView2 != null)
        {
            // Assign the NewWindow handle to the new WebView2 element
            e.NewWindow = newWebView2.CoreWebView2;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle the failure case if initialization fails
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to initialize new WebView2 instance.");
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exceptions
        MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        e.Handled = false;
    }
}

However my main WebView2 is crashing with BrowserProcessExited.
If I just change the line e.NewWindow = newWebView2.CoreWebView2; to newWebView2.Source = new Uri(e.Uri); I get a new Tab, a new WebView2, and the requested Uri is displayed. So the WebView2 initialization should be fine. The strange thing is, that I also get the new WebView2 window with the content - so it seems that e.Handled is not called, maybe not in time?
Moreover I think the prefered way is to use the NewWindow Element.
Has anybody an idea, why it's not working if I set the NewWindow to the new CoreWebView2 I am creating?
Thanks!

This question is similar to: Opening the URL in child window using the CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
